# MySQL random with specific options

Tags: mysql, sql, rows, myisam

I needed to get 20 random rows from the database. I got this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE 1 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 20
```

Everything works fine, but there is 1 problem.

- If there are less than 20 rows in the database, for example 13, then how to duplicate 7 more random rows until in the answer is exactly 20 rows?

*P.S. Don't worry about the emptiness. The table is never empty.*

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this? Why would you want to repeat data if number of rows is less than 20

Comment: What if there's only 3 rows? What if there's only 1 row?

Comment: Everything that I could provide, I already did. Sorry, but I cannot tell what I want to achieve. I need only solutions for my problems.

Comment: @Strawberry, I already answered your question, read carefully, please :)

Comment: What server side language are you using? What's the absolute maxmimum number of records that you expect will be in the table at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this with a stored procedure. This one selects random rows into a temporary table until the desired number of rows has been inserted. If there are enough rows in the source table, only one insert into the temporary table, of enough random rows to satisfy the request. If not, the entire contents of the table are inserted into the temporary table enough times to fill it. For example, when selecting 20 random entries from a table with only 8 rows, it will insert all 8 rows of the table (in random order) into the temporary table, then all 8 rows again (in a different random order) and then finally 4 random rows. Then the entire contents of the temporary table are returned.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS select_random //
CREATE PROCEDURE select_random (IN tablename VARCHAR(256), IN numrows INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE rowcnt INT DEFAULT numrows;
  SET @q = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE random LIKE ', tablename);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  SET @q = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @totrows FROM ', tablename);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  REPEAT
    SET @q = CONCAT('INSERT INTO random SELECT * FROM ', tablename, ' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ', LEAST(@totrows, rowcnt));
    PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    SET rowcnt = rowcnt - @totrows;
  UNTIL rowcnt <= 0
  END REPEAT;
  SELECT * FROM random;
  DROP TABLE random;
END
//
CALL select_random('table_name', 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you try:

```
SELECT * FROM 'tablename' WHERE 1 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

and do it 20 times. You might want to store the results in a new table, maybe using Select Into or/and Insert Into.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this method is not what I want. If I use this query 20 times and there are more than 20 rows in the table, then I can get duplicate rows in the result. In short, I don't want to get duplicated rows if in the table more then 20 rows.

Comment: @bek but that said this will happen when it is less than 20? you need to be very sharp with your problem description.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ, I am sorry for that, yes I said that this must happen when it is less than 20, but I didn't say that I need duplicates when it is more or equal to 20.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want then. If your table has less than 20 rows and you still want to force 20 random picks, you must get duplicates then. If not, you need to incorporate some kind of a formula, a calculation. Yet I don't know what are your database numbers, so no idea what formula this would be.

Comment: @bek - You changed the rules.  Technically speaking, 20 _random_ rows out of 1000 _could_ have duplicates.  Now you want no dups if there are more than 20 in the table?